# Non Duplicate values Copy Paste

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have hundreds of thousands of records and I want to find only non duplicate values in Excel.  From the column A I want to past the Values in column C which are not equal to B. Can someone help me on the same.

```
    A   |   B   |   C
 -------|-------|-------
    1   |   4   |   1
    2   |   5   |   2
    3   |   6   |   3
    4   |   7   |   13
    5   |   8   |   14
    6   |   9   |   15
    7   |   10  |   
    8   |   11  |   
    9   |   12  |   
    10  |   16  |   
    11  |   17  |   
    12  |       |   
    13  |       |   
    14  |       |   
    15  |       |   
    16  |       |   
    17  |       |
```

I already tried by pasting my values in C and putting this formula in B column as well..But this is not working after some cells.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$10000,0)),"",A1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a workaround for your problem using a helper column say `Column E` (change column E as needed).

In the `Cell E2` write the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF(E1:$E$1, $A$2:$A$20)+(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$20, $A$2:$A$20)<>1),0,0), 0)),"")
```

then drag/copy this formula down as required. This will give you non-duplicate numbers from `Column A`.

Then in `Cell C2` enter the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$20,MATCH(0,IFERROR(MATCH($E$2:$E$20,$B$2:$B$12,0),COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,$E$2:$E$20)),0)),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and drag/copy this formula down as required and you'll have your desired result as shown in the image below:

[image]

**EDIT :** VBA Solution
**________________________________________________________________________________**

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim dict1 As Object, dict2 As Object, dict3 As Object
    Dim c1 As Variant, c2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long

    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dict3 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  '-->get last row of Column A
    c1 = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    'add unique values in Column A to dict1
    For i = 1 To UBound(c1, 1)
        dict1(c1(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row  '-->get last row of Column B
    c2 = Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
    'add unique values in Column B to dict2
    For i = 1 To UBound(c2, 1)
        dict2(c2(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i

    'check existence of dict1 values in dict2
    'if not present add to dict3
    For Each k In dict1.keys
        If Not dict2.exists(k) Then
            dict3.Add k, 1
        End If
    Next k

    'display dict3 in Column C
    Range("C2").Resize(dict3.count) = Application.Transpose(dict3.keys)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this, I tried for 100 records it work perfectly, I think this formula can be helpful for small number of records. as I am facing the same problem its taking a lot of time for 1500 rows only, as I am having more than 100 thousand records so may not work on this. Is there any kind of VBA code so that we can avoid the formula and can make it quick and can get result. or may be in sql. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RakeshGupta - I've added a VBA solution.